# waterline js: custom attribute method access adapter

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a model backed by a custom adapter. When I write a custom attribute method, how can I get ahold of the adapter? In fact,

```
<Model>.connections.<connection-name>._adapter
```

works... but is there anything less hacky?

If not, then why not? My Model represents metadata for a spreadsheet, and I want to implement a custom controller method that gets the spreadsheet data. As its specific to the particular Model instance, I thought having the controller call an attribute method, which in turn asks the adapter, would be the way to go, but perhaps I should be implementing some other way?